# Power/energy density of an actuator

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, actuator

What is the meaning of power/energy density of an actuator?

Context:
As a novel kind of actuator, the dielectric elastomer ( DE )
demonstrates high-strain response [ 1 ] , high energy densities
( seventy times higher than conventional electromagnetic
actuators ) [ 2 ] , and high energy conversion ef ﬁ ciencies ( 60% –
90% [ 3 ]) .

Answer (score 2):

Power density is defined and understood as the average power over the weight and/or volume of the actuator (depending on the unit). Here, it is understood as the effective power output divided by weight (or volume)

For example, if your actuator is made from $2kg$ of DE and delivers $5W$ worth of power, then the power density is $5/2=2.5W/kg$

Thanks @Phil Sweet for this comment. I'd add an example for power density per unit volume.

Again, the DE actuator is $5W$ in output, and it has a volume of $0.02m^3$, the its power density will be $5/0.02=250W/m^3$

Comment: With any luck, it is *only* used for volume. *Specific energy* and *specific power* should be used for per-unit-mass terms. I don't get too worked up if this isn't the case, but please change the example to reflect the preferred usage.